# Injection counterexample for right inverse (updated)

Tags: functions

If $f: A\rightarrow B$ is injection, then $f$ has a right inverse?

For example I have this: $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)= x/2$ if is x is even or 4 if x is odd
So $g°f(x)=x$ but $f°g(x)$ is not equal to x
Does this prove anything?

Comment: Can you think of any injection that is not invertible?

Comment: No, but if f is injection then there is $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}°f =I_a$ right? But i think that i need to find ando f that is injection but not surjective. Ir am i not understanding at all the exercise.

Comment: See these: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Surjection_iff_Right_Inverse

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(\frac x2) = 2\cdot \frac x2 = x$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can you have $|A|=1$, $|B|=2$?

Comment: I was thinking about x that goes to x^2 but it is not injective. So think I can't have |A|=1 and |B|=2? So there is no counterproof?

Comment: @LexieWalker Of course there is.